# PHP+MySQL: How to fetch just limited count of results?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I have a DB table with 100-200k records and I need to optimize it. For example, if a user want to search the term **car**, he will get around 25k results.

I would like to offer him just let's say 500 newest results, but how to do that? I know I have to use `LIMIT`, but I am not sure, how to "group" just the newest 500 rows.

For making a better picture how I am fetching data from database now, here's a little snippet:

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string(searched_query($_GET['skill'])); 
$q = "...long sql query...";
echo $q;
$result = mysql_query($q);
$items = 30; // number of items per page.
$all = $_GET['a'];

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($all == "all"){
    $items = $num_rows;
}
$nrpage_amount = $num_rows/$items;
$page_amount = ceil($num_rows/$items);
$page_amount = $page_amount-1;
$page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['p']);
if($page < "1"){
    $page = "0";
}
$p_num = $items*$page;
// Query that you would like to SHOW
$result = mysql_query($q." ORDER BY published DESC LIMIT $p_num , $items");
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By ordering by `published DESC` you have already ordered the list from newest to oldest. So if you apply the `limit` of 500, it will automatically only fetch the newest 500 rows...

So Mysql will order first, and then  apply the limit.

Comment: @user1946705, MySQL's LIMIT **IS** pagination

Answer (score -1):

Use `ORDER BY` in the query. Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) for more details

Comment: @saratis : Missed that part. Sorry for my ignorance